# Prettier with top level async

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, prettier

There is a way to use async top level with prettier ?

I'm actually trying to ignore my await top level with `/prettier ignore` but prettier, ignore this line ...

Comment: related? https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports/issues/119

Comment: What happens when you run Prettier with top-level await? Does it fail to parse?

Comment: 2BH man I dropped prettier a little while back because they are just to slow to update there formatter with new TC-39 features added to the ECMA-262 specification. ESLint has become so highly configurable, that I use that, and if I want the additional bias formatting I use VS Codes formatter, which of course requires using vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Prettier to ignore line(s) with the following comment.

```js
// prettier-ignore
const res = await asyncFunc();
```

This will make Prettier ignore the following line.

If you, however, want to make Prettier ignore multiple lines, then you can do something like this:

```js
// prettier-ignore
{
const res = await asyncFunc();
const data = await getData();
}
```

This will make Prettier not format the code surrounded by `{ }`. The comments and brackets/parentheses might help you with making Prettier ignore top-level `await`.

---

**EDIT:** The easiest option, though, is to just use an `async` function (until Prettier supports it).

```js
(async (param) => {
  await getData(param);
})()
```

The anonymous `async` function above will call itself straight away, so it'll act like `await` has no `async` function.

With this method, Prettier will be happy.

Comment: This is what I tried, but when I do ``prettier --write "*/.{ts,tsx,.md}"`` I continue to get this error : "Syntax error await is only within async function"

Comment: Did you try adding a `.prettierignore` file? [See the docs for more information.](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files)

Comment: It might just be easier to surround your `await` line with an `async` function. After some researching, it turns out that there is no easy way to avoid this.

Comment: Indeed, it's work if I ignore the specific file, but it's dirty to ignore the whole file ?

Comment: True... Maybe just wrap your `await` code inside a self-callable `async` function, like the edit shows.

Comment: Of course, thanks for your help, dude !